# Scrollbar not appearing when size of JTextField goes over its predefined size

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jtextfield

I'm trying to implement a scrollbar in a JTextField using JScrollPane.

this is what I have:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    
    public class WordList extends JFrame {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WordList list = new WordList();
            list.buildFrame();
        }
        
        public void buildFrame() {
            JTextField wordField = new JTextField(20);
            JScrollPane wordScroll = new JScrollPane(wordField);
            wordScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            wordScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            wordScroll.setMaximumSize(wordScroll.getPreferredSize());
            
            this.getContentPane().add(wordScroll);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

However when I run the program I do not see a scrollbar when the length of the text exceeds a certain length...

Except when I do this:

I change `JTextField wordField = new JTextField(20);` to `JTextField wordField = new JTextField("ABCDEFG");`

When I do this the scrollbar appears when I type a lot of characters

What's wrong with my code? Why does the scrollbar not appear even when the amount of characters exceed a certain amount?

Comment: Use `JTextArea` instead of `JTextField`

Comment: JTextArea does work nicely, but why does this happen when I use JTextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WordList extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordList list = new WordList();
        list.buildFrame();
    }

    public void buildFrame() {

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextField wordField = new JTextField(20);

        JScrollBar wordScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
        wordScroll.setModel(wordField.getHorizontalVisibility());

        contentPane.add(wordField);
        contentPane.add(wordScroll);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Your code does not work because the entire content pane is just a single text field that does not support word wrap (hence why JScrollPane does not work, since it needs your content to be wrapped) and the text will always overflow out of the field length without resizing itself (not wrapped). You should use either JTextField with JScrollBar with a BoxLayout with Y axis to make the contents stack on top of each other vertically, or use JTextArea with JScrollPane instead.

Comment: While this code does work nicely, I would appreciate some explanations of why my code fails to display the scrollbar...